# dart ubuntu package is behind the latest release

Tags: dart, installation, apt

I've installed dart using apt as per the instructions here:

https://dart.dev/get-dart#install-using-apt-get

The latest version of dart is 2.8.4

The apt package is still on 2.8.1.

Am I doing something wrong or is google just being slow to update the apt packages?

Comment: `apt update && apt install dart` then `dart --version`

Comment: or: `wget https://storage.googleapis.com/dart-archive/channels/stable/release/latest/linux_packages/dart_2.8.4-1_amd64.deb && dpkg -i /dart_2.8.4-1_amd64.deb`

Comment: @num8er that is what I'm doing already and it reports 2.8.1.  As to the deb I'm aware it exists but was trying to avoid manual installs. My query was really about whether there was an issue with the apt repo I had convigured.